# Android - android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-inflate

I'm trying to implement android-viewflow application developed by Patrik Akerfeldt. 
The source code is here: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

I've added "**view-flow**" folder as a library project and referenced it in my application. When I want to use "***org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator***", the compiler gives the following error:

"***Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator***"

Here this is .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.alperen.osman.deneme"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator
            android:id="@+id/viewflowindic" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            app:footerLineHeight="2dp"
            app:customTypeface="fonts/Antic.ttf"
            app:footerTriangleHeight="10dp" app:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" app:selectedColor="#FFFFC445" app:footerColor="#FFFFC445" 
            app:titlePadding="10dp" app:textSize="11dp" app:selectedSize="12dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" app:clipPadding="5dp">
        </org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator>

    </LinearLayout>
    <org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow
        android:duplicateParentState="true" android:id="@+id/viewflow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow>
</LinearLayout>
```

This widget is used in .java code as below:

```
...

        TitleFlowIndicator indicator = (TitleFlowIndicator) findViewById(R.id.viewflowindic);
        indicator.setTitleProvider(adapter);
        viewFlow.setFlowIndicator(indicator);

...
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the **full** stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: I've already used logcat DDMS and examined the **full** stack trace of the error. Then I posted this issue.

Comment: "I've already used logcat DDMS and examined the full stack trace of the error" -- if you had, you would have found the actual exception, rather than the one you pasted. The one you pasted basically says "we had a problem -- keep reading to find the actual exception".

Comment: it might be helpful to see the full stack trace of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove this line :

```
app:customTypeface="fonts/Antic.ttf"
```